# Schwartz class functions whose Hilbert transforms are integrable must have integration zero

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

As in textbook:Fourier Analysis (Javier Duoandikoetxea)

> In the Schwartz class it is straightforward to characterize the
> functions whose Hilbert transforms are integrable: for $\phi \in
> > \mathcal{S}, H \phi \in L^{1}$ if and only if $\int \phi=0$.

I have proved one side of this proposition:
(2) $H \phi \in L^1$ then $\|H \phi\|_1<+\infty$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|H \phi\|_1=\int_R|H \phi| d x & \\
\geqslant \int_R H \phi d x & =\int_R \lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|y|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\phi(x-y)}{y} d y d x \\
& =\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|y|>\epsilon} \int_R \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\phi(x-y)}{y} d x d y \\
& = \lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|y \mid>\epsilon} \frac{\|\phi(x-y)\|_1}{\pi y} d y \\
& =\|\phi\|_1 \lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|y|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{y} d y
\end{aligned}
$$
$\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{| y| >\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} d y$ is not bounded, while $\|H \phi\|_1$ is bounded.

But the other side of this question I am not sure.

Comment: $\int \phi=0$ is different from $\|\phi\|_1=0$.

Comment: So seems I cannot prove this at all...

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4079117/627612